# Execute callback from spock mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I am writing a `Java` application using `Groovy Spock` for testing. In the controller, I want to test that something happened in a utilities function.
The utilities function accepts a `String` and 2 callbacks (`Consumer`).
Mocking the utility function, how can I execute one of the callbacks?

Java

```
public void authenticate(String token, Consumer<User> success, Consumer<Throwable> failure)
```

Groovy

```
def "..."(){
  given:
  TokenHandler th = Mock()
  // execute the failure callback
  th.authenticate(_) >> { token, success, failure -> failure.accept() }
}
```

Comment: Post the whole code of the Spock test. As it is now it looks like you are trying to mock the class that you also want to test. This does not make sense (unless you want to use Spock spies)

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the mock is wrong please see the following initialization:

```
Consumer<User> successConsumer = new Consumer<User>()
Consumer<Throwable> failureConsumer = new Consumer<Throwable>()

TokenHandler tokenHandlerMock = Mock(TokenHandler){
    th.authenticate(_) >> [token, successConsumer, failureConsumer]
}
```